# When using pipenv to create a virtual env I am getting a FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, pipenv

### Pipenv not working

When I try to use pipenv in my wsl shell this happens. I have used pipenv in the past but all of a sudden today it isn't working. I tried uninstalling and reinstalling pipenv but it isn't working.

```
pipenv install django
```

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.1.43ubuntu1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:123: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 1.1build1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  warnings.warn(
Creating a virtualenv for this project...
Pipfile: /mnt/d/Projects/To-do-list/Pipfile
Using /usr/bin/python3 (3.10.4) to create virtualenv...
⠴ Creating virtual environment...created virtual environment CPython3.10.4.final.0-64 in 612ms
  creator CPython3Posix(dest=/home/edzy/.local/share/virtualenvs/To-do-list-JHrSlGzr, clear=False, no_vcs_ignore=False, global=False)
  seeder FromAppData(download=False, pip=bundle, setuptools=bundle, wheel=bundle, via=copy, app_data_dir=/home/edzy/.local/share/virtualenv)
    added seed packages: pip==22.2.2, setuptools==63.4.1, wheel==0.37.1
  activators BashActivator,CShellActivator,FishActivator,NushellActivator,PowerShellActivator,PythonActivator

✔ Successfully created virtual environment!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/edzy/.local/bin/pipenv", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1128, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/options.py", line 56, in main
    return super().main(*args, **kwargs, windows_expand_args=False)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1053, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1659, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 1395, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
    return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/vendor/click/core.py", line 754, in invoke
    return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/cli/command.py", line 233, in install
    do_install(
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1942, in do_install
    ensure_project(
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 552, in ensure_project
    ensure_virtualenv(
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 485, in ensure_virtualenv
    do_create_virtualenv(
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/core.py", line 1008, in do_create_virtualenv
    project._environment = Environment(
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 79, in __init__
    self._base_paths = self.get_paths()
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/environment.py", line 390, in get_paths
    c = subprocess_run(command)
  File "/home/edzy/.local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pipenv/utils/processes.py", line 75, in subprocess_run
    return subprocess.run(
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 501, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 966, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "/usr/lib/python3.10/subprocess.py", line 1842, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/edzy/.local/share/virtualenvs/To-do-list-JHrSlGzr/bin/python'
```

Comment: Pip cannot find your python interpreter in `'/home/edzy/.local/share/virtualenvs/To-do-list-JHrSlGzr/bin/python'`. Can you please check if the python interpreter is existing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you haven't activated the virtual environment - try `pipenv shell` then `django-admin ...`

Answer (score 0):

You need to run pipenv with the python associated with the pip3.

so `python3 -m pipenv shell` considers that pip3 is associaed with python3. (if you have multiple version of python then you have to define which to use like : **python3**)

If it is not working then you can install pipenv again with the python as
`python3 -m pip install pipenv` and `python3 -m pipenv shell` (this cmd create venv)

then try this `pipenv install django` or `pipenv install django==3.2.14`

hope it'll help you.